# Map fragment lag on scroll

Tags: java, android, performance, google-maps, android-fragments

I am using a Google Maps fragment with a MapView that starts by getting user location and setting a marker with it. But i noticed a lag when user scrolls the map, it's like a frame drop.

I searched for some reasons, but i guess it depends on my code. Something seems wrong, but i don't know what yet.

Here's the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setFragment(new MapFragment());
}

protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

**MapFragment.java**

```
GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
MapView mMapView;
View mView;
LocationManager mLocationManager;
Location mUserLocation;

private final String TAG_PARSING_STYLE_FAILURE = "ERROR PARSING JSON";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    mView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
    return mView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mMapView = (MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.testMapView);

    if( mMapView != null){
        mMapView.onCreate(null);
        mMapView.onResume();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    }

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());

    mGoogleMap = googleMap;
    mGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

    mUserLocation = getUserLocation();
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(mUserLocation.getLatitude(), mUserLocation.getLongitude());

    MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.position(latLng);
    marker.title("My Location");

    mGoogleMap.addMarker(marker);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(latLng).zoom(17).build();

    mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}



public Location getUserLocation(){
    Location loc = null;
    try {
        loc = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.e("ERROR - LOCATION", ex.toString());
    }
    return loc;
}
```

Is there a better approach when using MapFragments?

Comment: Have you run this through a profiler?  Has that given any clues?

Comment: Yes, it seems to be not a performance issue. GPU/CPU/Memory is ok. Also, if i create a new Map Application from Android Studio it runs smoothly.

Comment: Could it be that you have issue with touch event in your view hierarchy ? like a map inside scrolview ...etc

Comment: Hmmm, i don't know, my view only contains the mapview and nothing more. Since i'm not very familiar with Android, my first shot is that my code is not very nice.